# I downloaded Dwarf Fortress. Why won't it run?

Tags: package-management, games, dependencies, sdl

I downloaded the version of Dwarf Fortress for Linux onto my computer, but when I click on the `df` file, it doesn't do anything. When I run it in a terminal, it gives me this message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Self-explanatory `No such file or directory`,install SDL libraries

Comment: See this thread at this forum: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=66142.315

Comment: I've had tons of trouble with getting DF to run because I'm on a 64-bit system, and getting the 32-bit dynamic library binaries to cooperate was quite a pain. There are workarounds, but I didn't find it worth my time.

Answer (score 13):

The Dwarf Fortress archive you downloaded features no dependency resolution, and that error indicates you haven't installed the necessary libraries to play.

Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
```

That should allow Dwarf Fortress to run correctly unless you are on a 64-bit installation. On 64-bit installations, you may need to add ":i386" as seen here:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libopenal1:i386
```

You may also run into problems with sound. If so, you can follow the directions on the dwarf fortress wiki, which suggest the following:

```
$ cd df_linux/libs
$ ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 ./libopenal.so
$ ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 ./libsndfile.so
```

Comment: NOTE: If DF or Desura (which handles dependency resolution) ever lands in the Software Center, instructions to install that way should supersede these.

Comment: Meta question: [Is it good practice to recommend users install software from third-party app stores?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2023/24694)

Comment: Seems to be an incomplete answer, at least on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @Kzqai - I updated the answer to show the proper packages to get the game running on a 64-bit installation (at least in 14.04).

Comment: On Linux Mint 17.3 (64-bit), the command `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0` sufficed without the need for the `:i386` counterparts

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and found a very easy workaround.  Install Wine using software center and download the windows version of Dwarf Fortress.

After Dwarf Fortress is downloaded and wine is installed, go in dwarf fortress folder and right click Dwarf Fortress.exe and select Open With and then wine program loader.  It just works. I thought it was easier than playing around with the libraries.